# Regular expression for matching ordered list item elements in HTML

Tags: c#, regex

I would like a regular expression (preferably in C#) that matches all list item element tags (`<li>`) in HTML, that reside within an ***ordered list*** element (`<ol>`). I do not wish to match the textual representation of the list items, just the opening tags, and understand that there may not be closing tags present. There may also be attributes present, such as the style attribute.

HTML code example:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li>Apple
<li>Banana
<li style=color:red>Cherry
</ul>
<ol>
<li>Avocado
<li>Beetroot
<li style=color:orange>Carrot
</ol>
<ul>
<li>Test Item A</li>
<li>Test Item B</li>
<li>Test Item C</li>
</ul>
<ol>
<li>Test Item 1</li>
<li>Test Item 2</li>
<li>Test Item 3</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

So, I am expecting that Avocado, Beetroot, and Carrot item element opening tags (not inner text) be matched, and also Test Item 1, Test Item 2, and Test Item 3 item elements be matched. However, I do not want any other item elements matched, since they are in unordered lists (`<ul>`).

There should be 6 resulting matches:

```
<li>
<li>
<li style=color:orange>
<li>
<li>
<li>
```

Note that I *do not* need for the closing tags (`</li>`, if any exist) to match.

I understand that lists can be nested (one list inside another), but I'm just looking for something simple at the moment.

I am not well versed with regular expressions, and I have tried many combinations. The last expression I tried, I used look behind and look ahead features:

In a simple (albeit incomplete) version, I was able to get the first item in the ordered lists, but not the rest:

```
(?<=<ol>)[^<]*<li[^>]*>
```

I then tried the following, but did not get any matches:

```
(?<=<ol>)[^<]*<li[^>]*>(?=</ol>)
```

I also understand the security implications in the use of regular expressions. However, since I am developing a screen reading application, this should not be an issue.

Comment: Why would you use regex here? C# has plenty of libraries to parse HTML.

Comment: You can try using AngleSharp to parse the HTML list elements

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, I would prefer not to use third-party libraries (aside from Microsoft libraries) in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this regex pattern:

```
(?:<ol>\s*)((?<group_li><li[^>]*>)[^<]*(</li>)?\s+)+(?:\s*</ol>)
```

The idea is captured each open tag of `li` element inside an `ol` into a named group `group_li`, using this group pattern `(?<group_li><li[^>]*>)`

Below is the sample code snippet that prints all matched `li` elements

```
string input = @"<div>
               <ul>
               <li>Apple
               <li>Banana
               <li style=color:red>Cherry
               </ul>
               <ol>
               <li>Avocado
               <li>Beetroot
               <li style=color:orange>Carrot
               </ol>
               <ul>
               <li>Test Item A</li>
               <li>Test Item B</li>
               <li>Test Item C</li>
               </ul>
               <ol>
               <li>Test Item 1</li>
               <li>Test Item 2</li>
               <li>Test Item 3</li>
               </ol>
             </div>";
Regex expression = new Regex(@"(?:<ol>\s*)((?<group_li><li[^>]*>)[^<]*(</li>)?\s+)+(?:\s*</ol>)");

// get all matches 
MatchCollection matches = expression.Matches(input);

// print all matched li
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    foreach (var li in match.Groups["group_li"].Captures) {
        Console.WriteLine(li);
    }
}
```

See demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/URnGo3)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I didn't know that you could extract substrings from named groups like that. You learn something new every day.

Comment: Sorry, but I thought you had it, then realised your expression still includes the list item text! I am after the following: `<li><li><li style=color:orange><li><li><li>`. The first two list items matched should be the opening tags from Avocado and Beetroot from the first ordered list, and then also match the opening tags from the second ordered list. I will update my question to clarify.

Comment: If you don't want to include item text, you could modify group pattern to only match opening tag of `li`. I've edited my answer, please check.

Comment: Thanks again, @Trung Duong. I have accepted your answer.